# How can I find out if I can add a bedroom to my home without violating any rules/ordinances?

Tags: building-regulations, new-home

I think I heard somewhere when I bought my home that we weren't allowed to add any permanent (concrete foundation) fixtures on my property, such as a shed on a concrete foundation.  Well, adding a bedroom to my home would do exactly this, does anyone know who I can contact to find out if this is even allowed?  Such as maybe an official city agency of some sort?

Comment: Is this prohibition a) city ordinance b) county ordinance c) gated community CC&R? The first two require checking with your local planning office, the last requires you to petition your community association.

Comment: Some municipalities have percentage limits of building coverage (land usage), which can be appealed to the zoning board for a variance (most town are loath to discourage an increase in tax base).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building regulations are generally controlled by either

- the municipality (city/town/township/village) if you live in one, or
- the county

Start with the first. Most often there is a planning or zoning office that regulates both commercial and residential construction.

Or you could consult a local builder and ask him or her what permissions you need (but double check any answer that you get; some unscrupulous builders will say you don't need any, and post construction, you may have a problem).

Comment: The way the question is worded, it's probably a CC&R. They have some silly requirements you buy into, such as requiring a wood shake roof for visual perfection despite the fact you are in a wildland interface zone where fire is a major concern (yes we have such a bunch of weirdos here, and the one resident had to fight mightily to get them to let him do a tile roof to abate fire danger)

Comment: @FiascoLabs An excellent point. The restriction would then be contractual and might even be a restriction on your deed.

Comment: @FiascoLabs What's CC&R?

Comment: Codes, Covenants & Restrictions. An excellent way that Americans have found to give away their property rights. It's supposed to keep your neighborhood from becoming trashy, but often is the source cause of much acrimony. For instance, you cannot change your house color (no bright pink) but there are times when your dictatorial neighborhood association will even demand that the paint be an exact match as in no change in tint. It can be a good thing, but often as with all micromanaging, leaves an opening for right gits to control every aspect of your life.

Comment: Covenants, Conditions and Restrictions. They are private contract property rules in addition to publicly mandated building codes and ordinances.